# How to start a session in PHP without loading the session page first?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am new to PHP!
I am talking about two PHP pages. One is index.php and another is cost.php.

The session should be started on the `cost.php` page. But when I load the `index.php` file for the first time after opening a browser the session does not start until I load the `cost.php` page. Thus I cannot access the session which is needed to start the index.php page.

**How can I start the session without loading the session page first?**

index page:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

$total_cost = $_SESSION['total_cost'];
$total_regular = $_SESSION['total_regular'];
$rate = $total_cost / $total_regular;
echo "The rate is = ".$rate;
?>
```

cost page:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

$total_cost = 12000 - $total_extra * 13;
$_SESSION['total_cost'] = $total_cost;
$_SESSION['total_regular'] = $total_regular;
?>
```

Comment: Post code from index.php and cost.php, use code snippets.

Comment: set session value `null` at first.
Please keep your mind,Community will eager to help you but you have to try something first ... then ask :)

Comment: Don't use isset($_SESSION) to check if session is started, but use session_status() http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. You don't start a session on `index.php`, you need to have `session_start()` on every page in which you want to use session variables.

Answer (score 0):

You must use

`session_start()` function in your `index.php` at top before accessing any session value.

`session_start()` either start or resume the session. If the session already existed those values will be loaded into `$_SESSION`, hence you can use them further.